# InnerHtml empty in HtmlContainerControl ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a rather specific question, that I couldn't find googling.

I have a div with a runat server like this:

```
<div id="Menu" runat="server">

<!--code-->
     <div><%= SomeValue %></div>
<!--code-->

</div>
```

The problem is that I need the InnerHtml of the element before the page finishes it's life cicle (to globalize it), but when I add the `<%=%>` the InnerHtml property comes back as `""` (if I remove it, it works fine).

For example:

1

```
<div id="Menu" runat="server">
  <span>Hi!</span>
</div>
//Menu.InnerHtml == "<span>Hi!</span>";
```

2

```
<div id="Menu" runat="server">
  <span>Hi!</span>
  <div><%= SomeValue %></div>
</div>
//Menu.InnerHtml == "";
```

Is there a way to have the InnerHtml and print `SomeValue` at the same time?

I guess can get around this some other way and this isn't really a good option, but I am dealing with existing code.

Thanks!

Comment: Define SomeValue ? Currently where you retrieve div's inner html, on _Page_Load()_ ?

Comment: SomeValue is defined (and printed correctly). Yes on Page_Load(), I've tried `OnUnload` but no luck.

Comment: Instead of using embedded code blocks _<%= %>_, why don't you set the inner html of inner div and store it in variable both at Page_Load() ? For instance, replace inner div with `<div id="innerMenu" runat="server"></div>` then use
 `string strGlobal = "value"; innerMenu.InnerHtml = strGlobal;`

Comment: @Coder That would be a solution, but I have this scenario repeated a lot of times in the code, so I would get really messy